# How is this " IF ELSE " statement called?

Tags: c#, if-statement

i sometimes use this kind of `if` in my code:

```
!Value == null ? DoSomething : DoSomethingElse;
```

and i was wondering what is the proper name for an `if else` statement like that.

also, i wonder if there can only be a `if` part, without the `else` in the same structure.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx

Comment: It is commonly referred to as the conditional operator or inline if (iif). (source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3A)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's called a [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). It is a ternary operator (and the only one), but that's not what it's called.

You can't use it as you can use an if statement. You can only use it where you need it to return one of two values. The two values need to be the same type, or an implicit conversion needs to exist between them.

Comment: Bloody Jon Skeet, hacking your answers to give you free reputation !

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx
thank you! added link if anyone is interested.

Comment: Many people dream of having their answers edited by Jon Skeet. Enjoy it.

Comment: Just a spelling mistake, I'm just glad I beat him to the answer :), although I managed to re-add the mistake.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your second question:

> also, i wonder if there can only be a if part, without the else in the same structure

The answer is 'kind of', if you want to check for a null, which is called a null coalesce. The syntax is similar and goes like this:

```
myVariable = aPossiblyNullValue ?? ReturnThisIfNull;
```

What this does is return the left hand side if the value is not null and if it is null, return the right.

Answer (score 0):

Its' called ternary operator and it works like...

```
!Value == null ? DoSomething : DoSomethingElse;
```

If value is not null (as you have added !) then do something (DoSomething will be called. Else, (means if the codition fails), then do something else (DoSomethingElse will be called).

Comment: DoSomething and DoSomethingElse both need to return something (that can be implicitly converted to the same thing), and it doesn't form a complete statement in itself, you need to use it with assignment, or a method call.